# Calling returned function results in "object is not callable" error

Tags: python

```
def hello_decorator(func):

    def inner():
        print('hello,this is before function execution')
        func()
        print('this is after function execution')

    return inner()

def hello():
    print('hello user')

hello = hello_decorator(hello)

hello()
```

add i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/se7en/Desktop/codeyad/pythonProject/p3.py", line 15, in <module>
    hello()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: `return inner` without `()`.

Comment: You did not return a function. You called the function, and returned what it returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning function. Instead, you are returning the value returned after function was called.
So, instead of calling function while returning, return function itself.

```
def hello_decorator(func):
    def inner():
        print('hello,this is before function execution')
        func()
        print('this is after function execution')
    return inner

def hello():
    print('hello user')

hello = hello_decorator(hello)

hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `return inner()`, you are trying to *call* the function and return the *result* (which is `None`)

If you want to return the decorated function itself, you need to omit the parentheses: `return inner`

Answer (score 1):

The **error** is `return inner()`.

**Reason error?** Using the parenthesis in `return inner`, you try to return the result of your function, which in this case is `None`. Therefore it cannot be recalled. You're returning the function itself, hence the None value obtained after calling the function.

The **solution** is to remove `()`, then just write `return inner`.

```
def hello_decorator(func):

    def inner():
        print('hello,this is before function execution')
        func()
        print('this is after function execution')

    return inner #correct

def hello():
    print('hello user')

hello = hello_decorator(hello)

hello()
```

Comment: @sara hajmirzaeyan If my answer, or that of other users, was the solution to your question, please accept the answer as per Stackoverflow Help Center rules, thank you